# Evaluating Excel Formula with 'PV' is not working with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

We are automating the comparison of API data with our excel data.
Excel data is our source of truth. It has Excel formulae given by our Product Owner. For the set of input the excel result should match with the API response.

The Excel formula has `PV` at one place and this evaluation is causing Exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected arg eval type (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.MissingArgEval)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.coerceValueToDouble(OperandResolver.java:271)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.NumericFunction.singleOperandEvaluate(NumericFunction.java:38)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.FinanceFunction.evaluate(FinanceFunction.java:53)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.FinanceFunction.evaluate(FinanceFunction.java:83)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:541)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:275)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:216)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.BaseFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(BaseFormulaEvaluator.java:185)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.BaseFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(BaseFormulaEvaluator.java:302)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAll(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:100)
    at com.tekioncloud.common.main.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

A simple working code:

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {
        XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("/Users/aarahman/Documents/ExcelPvCheck.xlsx"));
        xssfWorkbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
    }
```

The Excel and its formula looks like this:

[image]

Please let me know what am doing wrongly here.
Java - 8
Apache POI - 5.2.3

Comment: POI does not have full coverage for Excel functions. The POI code seems to require a non-empty 3rd param (left blank in your example). In practice, you don't use need to get POI to recalculate the formula results because Excel stores the results in the file and POI can read these values for you.

Comment: Thanks PJ Fanning that worked. You may mention it as answer too. Will mark it as answer. I didn't get that second part. After we update some value in Excel sheet, the formulas are not getting recalculated. Hence we need to call evaluateAll(), right? I even tried this too. I updated the value in excel, saved it and again opened it to check the formula, it remain unchanged. So, evaluate step is necessary. Please let me know if you were able to make it work in a different way.